# Partial info stored in task repository when execute tasks

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I am running a simple hello world task.
I am running the spring cloud data flow server backed by a Postgres db.

When I execute my task and then query the data flow server, I see:

```
dataflow:>task execution list
╔═════════╤══╤══════════╤════════╤═════════╗
║Task Name│ID│Start Time│End Time│Exit Code║
╠═════════╪══╪══════════╪════════╪═════════╣
║mytask   │5 │          │        │0        ║
║mytask   │4 │          │        │0        ║
║mytask   │3 │          │        │0        ║
║mytask   │2 │          │        │0        ║
║mytask   │1 │          │        │0        ║
╚═════════╧══╧══════════╧════════╧═════════╝
```

I did query the database as well:

```
anand=# select * from task_execution;

 task_execution_id | start_time | end_time | task_name | exit_code | exit_message | error_message |      last_updated       |            external_execution_id
-------------------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+---------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------
                 1 |            |          | mytask    |           |              |               | 2017-05-01 23:57:16.734 | mytask-87bc3b77-157d-4ff6-9b9a-d
                 2 |            |          | mytask    |           |              |               | 2017-05-01 23:57:57.762 | mytask-57d98d02-9aac-4283-a410-a
                 3 |            |          | mytask    |           |              |               | 2017-05-04 14:31:13.687 | mytask-5495ffd2-2f13-43bd-bdeb-5
                 4 |            |          | mytask    |           |              |               | 2017-05-04 14:37:06.435 | mytask-0063c9f5-df40-4eac-92d8-9
                 5 |            |          | mytask    |           |              |               | 2017-05-04 14:39:36.191 | mytask-98bbed0a-12e6-4318-b4f2-3
(5 rows)
```

Where am I going wrong that's causing the task execution info being partial in the database?

Comment: Just want to make sure ,  I am clear .. the  task does execute and thus  the records  of execution on the Table above ^^

Comment: I want also state that ,  when I run the timestamp test ,  it works  fine ...

Comment: Also ,  when I run the timestamp tests ,  it works fine ...

Comment: It could be a wrong driver or another dependency mismatch that might cause this. It'd be better if you can share your `mytask` application - we can review what's missing then.